# Passing parameters from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I would like to pass a data param when i click programmaticaly to a button:

```
// Somewhere in my code
$("#myButton").click(); // pass data here, example : {isValid : true}

// Event listener somewhere in the code
$("#myButton").off().on("click", function() {
  // How can i do to get isValid value here ?
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler , http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments with data attribute of event handler.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function(event, data){
   // data.isValid will hold your parameters
});

$('#myButton').trigger('click', {isValid : true});
```